# Exporting Excel spreadsheets in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm not very .NET or Javascript savvy so this is a bit too difficult for me. What's the easiest way to let a user download a Javascript `array` of objects in the form of an Excel spreadsheet? I know exporting it to CSV is the easiest way but I really need to export it in proper .xlsx format. As far as I understand, I will need to use the OpenXML sdk, but there's not much info (at least noob-friendly info) on how to actually approach it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just output a basic HTML table and set the appropriate response headers (Content-type):

> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

This will prompt the user to open Excel to view the file.

Answer (score 0):

Srry but i can't write comment so i answered your question...

You can use JavaScripts for this maybe.

Maybe you can use [this one](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/excel-export)

You should this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/750246/Export-Data-from-Database-Table-to-Excel-File-in-A) too i think...

I hope this answer will helpfull for you...

Check this pls;

[1]:

```js
$("[id$=myButtonControlID]").click(function(e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent( $('div[id$=divTableDataHolder]').html()));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
table
{
    border: 1px solid black;    
}
th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:skyblue;
    color: white;  
}
td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="myButtonControlID">Export Table data into Excel</button>
<div id="divTableDataHolder">
<table>
    <tr><th>ColumnOne </th><th>ColumnTwo</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>row1ColValue1</td><td>row1ColValue2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row2ColValue1</td><td>row2ColValue2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Folloiwng is a [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml) approach in ASP.Net MVC. It will help download files as `xlsx`

[image]

**GenerateExcelInvoiceController**

```
    private void GenerateExcelInvoiceController(ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook workBook, string formtFileName)
    {

        string currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        string headerString = formtFileName.Replace("{0}", currentTime);
        headerString = headerString.Replace(" ", "");
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", headerString);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workBook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
        Response.End();
    }
```

**ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook GetWorkBook**

```
    public static ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook GetWorkBook(DataTable table, string sheetName)
    {
        ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook workBook = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook();
        ClosedXML.Excel.IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheets.Add(table, sheetName);
        return workBook;
    }
```

**Controller Action for POST**

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public void PracticeList(BalanceStatementModel modelReceived)
    {

        List<FinanceEntity> rows = GetRunningBalanceDueForPractice();

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using (var reader = FastMember.ObjectReader.Create(rows, "ItemDescription", "EventDate", "Amount", "RunningBalanceDue"))
        {
            table.Load(reader);
        }

        ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook workBook =  CommonBusinessMethodHelpers.GetWorkBook(table, "Statement");
        string formtFileName = "attachment;filename=\"BalanceStatement-{0}.xlsx\"";
        GenerateExcelInvoiceController(workBook, formtFileName);


    }
```

Note: It uses [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member) librabry available via NuGet.

**References:**

1. [Making OpenXML Easy with ClosedXML](https://www.infoq.com/news/2011/07/ClosedXML)
2. [Use the library ClosedXml for creating Excel files](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Utilizzo-della-libreria-77c28353)